# PHP respect validation fatal error Class 'Respect\Validation\Validator' not found

Tags: php, validation, respect-validation

I downloaded [Respect](https://github.com/Respect/Validation)/validation zip file from here https://github.com/Respect/Validation/archive/master.zip

I unzipped the archive and added a php file named phpinfo.php @ /Validation-master/Validation-master/library/

this is the project structure [image]

the contents of the phpinfo file is

```
<?php
use Respect\Validation\Validator as v;

$usernameValidator = v::alnum()->noWhitespace()->length(1,15);

$valid = $usernameValidator->validate("alganet"); //$valid now == true
$valid = $usernameValidator->validate("ácido acético"); //$valid now == false
?>
```

I have an XAMPP installation running. I tried running the phpinfo.php file from my browser.

I am getting the Fatal error: Class 'Respect\Validation\Validator' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpproj\boots\Dropbox\EasyAccounts\validation\Validation-master\Validation-master\library\phpinfo.php on line 4

What should I do to load the class ?
I am a newbie in terms of PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should either [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) the file or use an [autoloader](http://php.net/autoload)

Comment: What is the file that I should include? Also please let me know how to include a file that is in another directory?

Comment: I tried auto loading but found it the hard way that it is a pain to do. Now I am going ahead with composer which is the recommended way of doing things.